# Use speakers even if earplug plugged in?

Tags: headset, speaker

I had an issue with the earplugs that broke in my phone, with a piece staying inside. The problem is that now the system detects the piece, so is permanently in earplug mode. I would like to set it in speaker mode instead. Is there a way I can ask (manually?) Android to be in speaker mode even when it detects an earplug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: Not yet but if this is necessary, I can see how to get root access.